# doctrine migration generate update when no change has been done

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I use doctrine migration to update my database. I've created an entity which hold and image sotre in a mediumtext :

```
/**
 * Avatar of the person
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", length=500000, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()  
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 0,
 *      max = 500000,
 *      minMessage = "Avatar must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Avatar cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
 * )  
 * @JMS\Groups({"user_avatar"})    
 */
 private $avatar;
```

So, Doctrine migration have generated this SQL to update my schema :

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE s_user_identity ADD avatar MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL');
```

But now every time I check the difference between my entities and my schema doctrine migration see a change

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE s_user_identity CHANGE avatar avatar MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL');
```

Even if a accept this migration, it will still propose me this modification of my schema.

Maybe the down can help you understand what is going on

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE s_user_identity CHANGE avatar avatar MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci');
```

I also tried with `doctrine:shema:update`, it also see a difference.
Does anyone have an idea on why doctrine does that ?

Comment: I see my migration sql passing in the console when I `d:m:m` and I also read 'Already at latest version' when I `d:m:s`. As I said to @sensorario, I can execute `d:s:u` as much as I want, It still need to execute 1 query.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  i am running into this now.